# on route change in react js call a function

Tags: reactjs, function, react-router, react-router-dom, react-lifecycle

Bellow is the App.js file. when ever I click on any of the nav bar the selected route is rendered.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Layout>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/success-cards" component={Success_Cards} />
                    <Route path="/failure-cards" component={Failure_Cards} />
                    <Route path="/snap-photo" component={Snap_Photo} />
                    <Route path="/all-cards" component={All_Cards} />
                    <Route path="/user-guide" component={User_Guide}/>
                    <Route path="/rejected-cards" component={Rejected_Cards} />
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

What I want is when I am clicking on some nav bar then it should call an API as a default to fetch few data. The challenging part is what method should I use to achieve on route change call a function to fetch data. Can anyone please help. I have tried comoponentDidMount, componentShouldMount etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) fetching data in componentDidMount is a right choice

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using hooks if you aren't, but otherwise a possible way to handle what you want would be to wrap each route's component in the same component, and put the `useEffect (hook version)` or `componentDidMount` functionality in that component. That way the same logic will fire off each time any route that is wrapped in it is rendered.